# Routing to a read only replica using a linked server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, alwayson

We have a 3 node AlwaysOn cluster with a primary node, one Read-Only node and a DR node that isn't in the routing list. I set up the read only replica and tested it with MS Access and it works.

Problem is we have hundreds of applications and it's a huge development headache to create a separate connection and then keep track of which stored procedure needs to use it.

I had an idea to create a second linked server, but of course it didn't work because the linked server name has to be the same as the server name.

Then i tried to create a new listener, but only one is allowed.

My next idea is I created a new DNS record and pointed it to the IP of the existing listener. I'm going to try to create a new linked server with a new name and have it routed to the read-only replica.

My ultimate goal is to find every stored procedure that is only used to return data and change it to use the new linked server name in order to be routed to the read only replica so that our devs don't have to create a new RO connection and hunt down every stored procedure, etc.

Is this possible?

Comment: what is the need for read only replica with linked server.sorry,I read twice ,but i am not able to understand the intent

Comment: some of our apps make heavy use of stored procedures and it would take a lot of development time to create a new connection and go through all the code to repoint some procedures to a read only connection. Using a linked server i can go through any SP that is only selects and point it to the read only linked server name